# How to create a derived attribute from a foreign table using Alter Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't create a derived column in the CREATE TABLE Command this time. I tried with the Alter Table but found the following error:

> "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE Bem (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   PRECO INT,
   NOME VARCHAR(128),
   CATEGORIA VARCHAR(128)
);
 

CREATE TABLE Orcamento (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   Nome VARCHAR(128),
   Valor INT
);

CREATE TABLE Inventario (
  ID_Bem INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bem(ID),
  ID_Orc INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orcamento(ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_Bem,ID_Orc)
);
```

I want **Orcamento(Valor)** to be a derived column, a **Sum of Bem(Preco)** for every item found on the Inventorio table that matches the Orcamento's ID.

This is what i tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Orcamento
  ADD ValorT
     AS
     (SELECT SUM(Bem.Preco)
         FROM Bem, Inventario
         WHERE Bem.ID = Inventario.ID_Bem 
            AND Inventario.ID_Orc = Orcamento.ID
     )
;
```

Using UPDATE worked, but it'd have to run this UPDATE every time i added data to the Inventario table. I'm wondering for better alternatives

Comment: It's 2025, it's long past time to stop using that 1980's syntax. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Oops, 2024 (I'm getting ahead of myself now!).

Comment: @ThomA you scared me there for a moment :D And to OP, this is a bad idea, why not use a view or calculate on the fly when you need this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it manually every time you want to update the column can be arduous. Would make sense to create a scalar UDF that populates this, something like the below, bit of a workaround.

**Scalar UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetOrcamentoValor (@OrcamentoID INT)  
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @Valor INT;  
SELECT @Valor = SUM(Bem.Preco)  
FROM Bem  
JOIN Inventario ON Bem.ID = Inventario.ID_Bem  
WHERE Inventario.ID_Orc = @OrcamentoID;  
RETURN ISNULL(@Valor, 0);  
END;
```

After this, change the Orcamento table to add the computed column using the UDF.

```
ALTER TABLE Orcamento  
ADD Valor AS dbo.GetOrcamentoValor(ID);
```

Whenever you insert or update a row in the Orcamento table, the Valor column will be automatically calculated using the logic defined in the scalar UDF.

Comment: Blargh, this *works*, but it's rarely a good idea (from a performance perspective). Better to create a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 2):

Storing aggregate data is rarely a good idea, and certainly doing it as a calculated column is *not* a good idea.

Instead, if you *need* to have this information readily available to query, create a `VIEW` with the definition defined in there for the aggregate value you need. This appears to be right, but with no actual sample data, just definitions, I've no way to confirm.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView AS
    SELECT O.ID,
           O.Nome,
           O.Valor,
           SUM(B.Preco) AS ValorT
    FROM dbo.Orcamento O
         --LEFT JOINs as I assume you still want a row if there are no related rows
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Inventario I ON Orcamento.ID = Orcamento.ID_Orc
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Bem B ON I.ID_Bem - B.ID
   GROUP BY O.ID,
            O.Nome,
            O.Valor;
```

Comment: I'll take this into consideration, a view might really be the best option

Comment: I can guarantee it's better than the scalar UDF solution, @Czarian .